# Registering for USB insertion/removal notifications (Windows Service)

Tags: c, windows-services

I am writing Windows Service which logs information on inserted or removed USB devices. RegisterDeviceNotification function returns valid handle, but SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT notifications still not come to service control handler function.

I used Tom Bell's "[Detecting USB Device Insertion and Removal Using Windows API](http://www.codemiles.com/download/file.php?id=719)" and "Creating your own Windows Service" from Habrahabr.

I'm new to Services and Windows API, so could you please [look at my code](http://pastebin.com/QjWZLwsJ) and tell what may be wrong? And if the code is correct, is there any pitfalls(?) connected with security restrictions or something like this?

**[EDIT moved from answer]**

The problem was not in code, but in incorrectly installed VirtualBox :)

Comment: Sorry for my English, please =)

Comment: You are missing the DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES flag in your call to RegisterDeviceNotification(), assuming you want notification of all devices.

Comment: Thank you for advice, unfortunately  it has no effect (

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in code, but in incorrectly installed VirtualBox :)